# Lidar com exceção que garantidamente não vai ocorrer

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, exceção

Segue um exemplo de método pra ilustrar o contexto da minha dúvida:

```
public void comprar(int numeroLoja, int numeracaoProduto, String nomeMarca) throws LojaNaoExisteException, ProdutoNaoExisteException, MarcaNaoExisteException {
    Loja loja = null;
    Produto produto = null;
    Marca marca = null;

    try {
        loja = obterLoja(numeroLoja);
    } catch (LojaNaoExisteException e) {
        throw e;
    }

    try {
        produto = obterProduto(loja, numeracaoProduto);
    } catch (ProdutoNaoExisteException e) {
        throw e;
    }

    try {
        marca = obterMarca(loja, produto, nomeMarca);
    } catch (MarcaNaoExisteException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Tendo esse cenário e sabendo que o método `obterProduto` pode lançar a exception  `LojaNulaException` e que o método `obterMarca` pode lançar as exceptions `LojaNulaException` e `ProdutoNuloException`, além disso o meu método comprar só pode lançar as exceptions declaradas com throws (`LojaNaoExisteException`, `ProdutoNaoExisteException`, `MarcaNaoExisteException`).

Com as condições acima é possível garantir que tanto `obterProduto` quanto `obterMarca` nunca irão lançar exceções referentes a objetos nulos, mas ainda assim eu tenho um erro de compilação, caso não trate essas exceções de alguma forma. Como posso resolver esse problema sem precisar lançar exceções referentes a objetos nulos no meu método `comprar`?

Comment: Não dá para entender muito bem o que deseja. Talvez o problema já esteja nos métodos chamados. Talvez essas exceções nem deveriam existir. Você diz que tem erro de compilação, mas não diz qual. Colocar um `throw e` dentro do `catch` é a última coisa que deveria fazer. Essa maneira de "tratar" exceções é a pior possível. A única garantia que isto dá é que problemas ocorrerão. Coloque mais informações e eu tento dar uma resposta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## TL;DR

A forma *correta* de lidar com exceções que não deveriam ocorrer é não usá-las em primeiro lugar.

## Deduzindo o cenário

Você deve ter o código mais ou menos assim:

```
Produto obterProduto(Loja loja, int numeracaoProduto) {
    if (loja == null) throw new LojaNulaException();
    ...
}
```

Esta é uma prática comum e já trabalhei em empresas que usavam exceção para tratar todos os casos "excepcionais" dos métodos (havia até uma planilha do excel para gerar as exceções automaticamente, tamanho era o número de classes).

## Analisando as Exceções

Existem pelo menos duas razões pelas quais não se deveria usar exceções assim:

### 1. Esse caso não é realmente excepcional.

Tratar nulos não é algo que faz parte dos fluxos planejados do sistema. Você não criaria um diagrama ou fluxograma para tratar cada parâmetro que pode ser nulo.

Com isso, não quero dizer que os parâmetros não devam ser verificados, pelo contrário. **Todo bom desenvolvedor verifica bem a entrada recebida**.

Entretanto, checagem de parâmetros é algo conhecido como **pré-condições**. Pré-condições são requisitos que precisam ser atendidos para que uma rotina realmente execute.

Como vou mostrar abaixo, existem outros mecanismos para tratar essas pré-condições.

### 2. Isso gera uma "burrocracia" desnecessária

Toda burocracia desnecessária torna o desenvolvimento pior. As pessoas não gostam, gasta-se mais tempo com coisas que não fazem sentido e não se resolve problema algum.

Especificamente nesse caso, você quer mesmo criar exceções específicas para todos os possíveis problemas que o seu programa pode ter? Por que não criar uma exceção para cada campo que não for preenchido.

Eu sei que muitos argumentam que isso ajuda o desenvolvedor a saber que ele não pode passar um nulo, mas isso simplesmente poderia estar documentado no método.

*"Ah, mas e se não seguirem a documentação?"*. Bem, para isso servem os testes. Se um desenvolvedor consegue colocar em produção um código que nunca foi executado, passando um argumento inválido, você tem um sério problema no processo de desenvolvimento.

E, no fim das contas, mesmo em casos difíceis onde não se pega um erro evidente como esse, não tem muita diferença o programa travar com um `LojaNula` ou `NullPointer`. O usuário não vai estar feliz. E com a pilha você pode facilmente encontrar o problema nos dois casos.

## Alternativas para tratar pré-condições ou casos que "não deveriam ocorrer"

### Exceções mais genéricas

Existe um motivo pelo qual as exceções tem uma **mensagem**. Elas podem ser reusadas, mas parece que muitos arquitetos esquecem disso.

Se um parâmetro possui um valor inválido, você pode fazer isso:

```
if (tamanho < 0)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Tamanho deve ser positivo!");
```

Se você quer evitar parâmetros nulos, uma alternativa simples é lançar:

```
if (parametro == null)
    throw new NullPointerException("Parâmetro XYZ não pode ser nulo!");
```

Se por acaso você tiver algum tratamento especial para seus parâmetros nulos (o que eu duvido), pode fazer algo assim:

```
throw new ParametroNulo("XYZ");
```

E no construtor da exceção você recebe somente o nome do parâmetro e gera uma mensagem mais amigável.

Eu sempre me espanto de ver como as pessoas se esquecem de que elas podem estender `Exception` e **adicionar atributos e argumentos ao construtor**.

### Asserções

Outra forma de tratar comportamentos inesperados é através de asserções.

O ponto aqui é saber traçar uma linha entre os **erros conhecidos** e os **inesperados**.

- Um problema esperado pode ser facilmente tratado com uma exceção. Você sabe que aquela é uma situação que tem uma probabilidade legítima de ocorrer. Mesmo assim verifica se já não existe uma exceção feita para isso.
- Um problema inesperado não precisa de uma exceção, você simplesmente pode fazer uma asserção do tipo: *isso nunca deveria ocorrer, mas se por acaso ocorrer, lance um erro*.

O Java tem um bom suporte à asserções e elas basicamente funcionam como exceções não verificadas.

### Google Guava [Preconditions](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r14/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html)

Guava é uma biblioteca conhecida for reforçar boas práticas. Uma delas é usar asserções para tratar as pré-condições.

Exemplo:

```
checkArgument(tamanho > 0, "Tamanho deve ser positivo: %s", count);
checkNotNull(loja, "Loja deve ser informada");
```

Os exemplos acima deve usar `import static` para importar os métodos da classe `Preconditions` e vão lançar exceções caso a checagem falhe.

Isso deixa seu código mais fácil de ler e exige menos digitação, diminuindo o emaranhado de `if`s se houver muitos casos

## Considerações

Todo projeto deve traçar a linha entre tratamento excepcional e de pré-condições.

Centenas e milhares de exceções não tornam o desenvolvimento melhor, então eu sugiro esquecer a velha e conhecida má prática de criar exceções padronizadas para cada entidade do seu CRUD (às vezes eu acho que as pessoas fazem isso só para se sentir no controle ou ter a impressão de que estão tendo mais produtividade).

Aliás, em todos casos onde você tem código praticamente gerado, talvez até um gerador de código, é melhor pensar e repensar dez vezes se não seria melhor criar um código unificado que possa ser reusado.

E se você caiu numa armadilha dessas e agora está tendo problemas para dar manutenção no código, reúna com a equipe e crie um mini-projeto de limpeza do código. Num projeto como o citado na pergunta, eu gastaria um ou dois dias removendo todas as exceções específicas e substituindo por outras mais genéricas e talvez asserções. Se tiverem muitos casos, uma substituição com Regex pode fazer grande parte do trabalho, senão todo.

Comment: Ótima resposta. É difícil mesmo para quem não está acostumado entender onde traçar a linha entre o que é um if e o que é uma exceção, ou o que é uma exceção não verificada e uma verificada. Especialmente para quem só aprendeu C na faculdade, com seus códigos de retorno e `errno`s.

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho certeza se entendi exatamente o problema, mas acredito que você possa tratar cada uma dessas exceções nulas separadamente, e disparar novas exceções dentro do tipo previsto na declaração do método `comprar`.

O código fica mais ou menos assim:

```
public void comprar(int numeroLoja, int numeracaoProduto, String nomeMarca) throws LojaNaoExisteException, ProdutoNaoExisteException, MarcaNaoExisteException {

    Loja loja = null;
    Produto produto = null;
    Marca marca = null;

    try {

        loja = obterLoja(numeroLoja);
        produto = obterProduto(loja, numeracaoProduto);
        marca = obterMarca(loja, produto, nomeMarca);

    } catch (LojaNulaException e) {
        // Trata LojaNulaException
        throw new LojaNaoExisteException();

    } catch (ProdutoNuloException e) {
        // Trata ProdutoNuloException
        throw new ProdutoNaoExisteException();

    } catch (MarcaNaoExisteException e) {
        // Trata MarcaNaoExisteException
        throw e;

    }
}
```

Esse encadeamento pode ser estendido conforme a necessidade:

```
    try {

        loja = obterLoja(numeroLoja);
        produto = obterProduto(loja, numeracaoProduto);
        marca = obterMarca(loja, produto, nomeMarca);

    } catch (LojaNulaException e) {
        // Trata LojaNulaException
        throw new LojaNaoExisteException();

    } catch (ProdutoNuloException e) {
        // Trata ProdutoNuloException
        throw new ProdutoNaoExisteException();

    } catch (LojaNaoExisteException e) {
        // Trata LojaNaoExisteException

    } catch (ProdutoNaoExisteException e) {
        // Trata ProdutoNaoExisteException 

    } catch (MarcaNaoExisteException e) {
        // Trata MarcaNaoExisteException
    ...
    ... 
    ...
    ... 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Trata outra possível Exception que possa acontecer

    } finally {
        // Opcional: executa um código de finalização 
    }
```

Uma outra possibilidade que deve solucionar o problema, é encadear os blocos de tratamento internamente.
Um exemplo de como ficaria o código:

```
    loja = obterLoja(numeroLoja);
    try {
        // Trata LojaNulaException
        produto = obterProduto(loja, numeracaoProduto);

        try {
            // Trata ProdutoNuloException
            // Se a marca não existir, já vai disparar MarcaNaoExisteException
            marca = obterMarca(loja, produto, nomeMarca);

        } catch (ProdutoNuloException e) {
            // dispara ProdutoNaoExisteException durante a busca da marca
            throw new ProdutoNaoExisteException();

        }

    } catch (LojaNulaException e) {
        // dispara LojaNaoExisteException durante a busca da marca ou produto
        throw new LojaNaoExisteException();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Geralmente quando não sei exatamente o que pode ocorrer, eu trato da seguinte forma:

```
try {
    //codigo
} catch (Exception e) {
    //Tratamento
}
```

O motivo de um tratamento assim, acho que é mais por segurança, claro deixando deforma muito mais muito genérica, você estará tratando todas as ocorrências somente de uma forma.

Sempre utilizo por questão de segurança, caso algo passe despercebido, pelo menos tenho a certeza que de alguma forma eu vou tratar no final.

Comment: Isso é terrível. Você está capturando todos os erros possíveis e fazendo a mesma coisa com todos eles. A única situação que consigo pensar na qual caberia isso é no mais alto nível do código (no main) para jogar erros em um arquivo especial ou exibir num diálogo antes de deixar a aplicação morrer. Em qualquer outro lugar isso pode engolir graves erros de programação: aplicação vai continuar rodando como se nada tivesse acontecido e você só vai saber que tem algo errado quando já não tiver uma forma de rastrear de onde veio o erro. Não faça isso!

Comment: Mais assim você pode estar logando o erro e captando eles para correção. Acredito que seja uma forma melhor do que deixar a aplicação cair para os usuários. Se ele estiver tratando as exceptions que ele conhece que podem ocorrer, e no final tratar o resto, qual mal tem? Trata o que conhece e no final loga o que passar despercebido... Não falei pra por simplesmente um "Exception e" sozinho, isso sim seria um grande erro.

Comment: Como eu disse, a única coisa sensata a se fazer nesse caso seria fazer um log da exceção (talvez enviando a um servidor de análise, por exemplo). Entretanto, deixar a aplicação cair para os usuários é **a coisa mais sensata a se fazer**. Não aceite a minha palavra como verdade-- veja o que o Chrome faz, por exemplo (aba morta) ou o Firefox (pede um relátorio e reinicia). Deixar a aplicação rodando após obter um erro desconhecido é muito perigoso para o(a) seu(ua) usuário(a). Um exemplo:

Comment: Imagine que você esteja criando um editor de texto (ou imagens, vídeos etc.): se você engole um erro desconhecido após enviar a um log, o que te garante que esse erro não tem algo a ver com, digamos, o salvamento do arquivo? O(a) usuário(a) pode achar que seus Ctrl-S estão funcionando pois o seu programa diz que estão, mas ele só está dizendo isso por causa de um bug causado por um estado inválido que não deveria ocorrer, mas ocorreu por causa da exceção desconhecida. Ele(a) pode perder horas de trabalho por conta disso. Agora imagine uma aplicação financeira? A conveniência não vale o risco.